# Require ip in apache2 works for index.html but not

Tags: apache2, gcp

I am using apache 2.4.56 and my site is hosted on Google Cloud Compute.
"Require ip ip-number" works for `/var/www/html/index.html` like `mysite.com` but it doesn't work for `mysite.com/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi?directory=%2CBrasil&submit_directory=`
In the second case, anybody can access it. This is what I have in the apache configuration file:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require ip 107.217.8.189
</Directory>
```

My scripts are in /usr/lib/cgi-bin.
How do I allow just one IP to access my scripts?

Thanks!

Comment: Please review how other posts format data, then update your post. The format of configuration details is important.

Comment: shouldn't you be using `mod_authz_host` rather than `mod_authz_core`? or is Apache documentation misleading?

Comment: I changed to mod_authz_host and restarted apache2 and still doesn't work. Even for my ip I get this: You don't have permission to access this resource.

Comment: show the full vhosts config and not just apart from it

Answer (score 0):

You configured the authentication in the context `<Directory /var/www/>`, so it only applies to files in `/var/www`. The `cgi-bin` directory is not inside that directory, so the authentication does not apply.

You should move it to a `<Location>` context.

```
<Location />
    Require ip 107.217.8.189
</Location>
```

Comment: It worked. I placed this directive inside apache2.conf. Is this the correct place? Also, why does "<Location />" require a "/>" at the end instead of just "<Location>"? Thanks!

Comment: There are various places, depending on your needs. If you place it inside a `<VirtualHost>` it will only apply to it, if you place it outside it will apply to all VirtualHosts (if not overridden inside of one). For details see [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location).